# Github not showing commits in my master branch in contribution

Tags: git, github

I Googled the same but after the answer were highlighting towards commit made towards a fork won't be counted.

My story happens to be different, I have my own **Public Repository**, I am making commits in **master branch**, I can see the commit history but unfortunately I can't happen to see them being counted under my contribution.

For example, this is my github profile https://github.com/irohitb and it shows I have done only one contribution today which is to create this repository.

But If i go to this repository, You can see there are 3 commits from today 
https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/commits/master

Any Idea why this might be happening?

Comment: You are probably being impatient. Look again tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your git config

```
git config --global user.name "Dav Glass"
git config --global user.email dav.glass@yahoo.com
```

The important part is for the email in your git config to match an email linked with your github profile. If you use a new email that isn't on your github profile then your github account won't be linked with the commits you make (that's why on your commits you can see your name but its not linkable- because there is a config issue)

If you add `.patch` to the end of a commit message you can see the email you used to make the commits. Stalking your github profile, I can compare these two patches

https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/commit/2c191c58cd0b83e185aa02d017c8249141e3fe85.patch

https://github.com/irohitb/burgerBuilder/commit/144dd604c5f809d759ca645240ff30982f9b96b5.patch

And I see that the emails are ever so slightly different. In one you use

`irohitbhatial@gmail.com` and in the other one you use `irohitbhatia@gmail.com`

Change your config to use `irohitbhatia@gmail.com` and you should see your commits behaving like normal again. Or add the other email (if its not a typo) to your github profile :)

See also: [Why Aren't My Contributions Showing up on my Profile](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/)